# Merging arrays where values are not null/none based on a particular element

Tags: python, arrays, merge

I've been trying to join multiple arrays with a common field with no success. I would like to go from a situation like this:

```
mainArray = [['dog', None, None, 'bark', None], 
             ['dog', 'brown', None, None, None],
             ['dog', None, 'happy', None, None],
             ['cat', 'black', None, None, None],
             ['cat', None, None, 'soft', None],
             ['cat', None, None, None, 'purr']]
```

To something like this:

```
mainArray = [['dog', 'brown', 'happy', 'bark', None],
             ['cat', 'black', None, 'soft', 'purr']]
```

I know this should be fairly simple but I have not been able to find a correct implementarion for this. Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Is the first item in each list a key?

Comment: What if there is another `dog` after `cat` at 0th index?

Comment: @ElliotRoberts, yes. The key is always the first item.

Comment: What if a position has more than one item?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri It should be considered as a normal field. The key is always the first element

Comment: @ElliotRoberts for the case I am trying to solve, it should not occur

Comment: @DiegoSt It would be more appropriate to add the requirements to the question and not leave them only in the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the key is the first item of each sublist, and mismatching fields don't overlap, here's one way to do this with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
from itertools import groupby, dropwhile

r = [[next(dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, i), None) for i in zip(*g)] 
                       for _, g in groupby(mainArray, lambda x: x[0])]
print(r)
# [['dog', 'brown', 'happy', 'bark', None], 
#  ['cat', 'black', None, 'soft', 'purr']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this did the job perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, assuming there's never more than one non-`None` value is each position of each sub-array (as shown in your example data):

```
import collections
from pprint import pprint

mainArray = [['dog', None, None, 'bark', None],
             ['dog', 'brown', None, None, None],
             ['dog', None, 'happy', None, None],
             ['cat', 'black', None, None, None],
             ['cat', None, None, 'soft', None],
             ['cat', None, None, None, 'purr']]

temp_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
for row in mainArray:
    key = row[0]
    if key not in temp_dict:
        temp_dict[key] = [row[1:]]
    else:
        temp_dict[key].append(row[1:])

mainArray = []
for key,rows in temp_dict.items():
    merged = [None] * len(rows[0])
    for row in rows:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i] is not None:
                merged[i] = row[i]
    mainArray.append([key] + merged)

pprint(mainArray)
```

Output (which is correct, although slightly different than what you showed):

```
[['dog', 'brown', 'happy', 'bark', None],
 ['cat', 'black', None, 'soft', 'purr']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll keep the above solution, but I believe this should work as well